# Cannot exclude a dependency inside a jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project (B) which compile a local jar (A). I need to exclude a dependency inside the jar (A) but I can't do it when building the jar. I can build the jar how ever I want but I have to have those dependencies in it and only exclude them in project B.

This is build.gradle the jar of project A:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'test'
    version =  '0.1.0'

    manifest {
        attributes ("Main-Class": "Main")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE") // I need this excluded later
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:1.4.0.RELEASE") // I need this excluded later
    /*
    some other dependencies here
    */
}
```

This is build.gradle for project B:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir(dirs: "lib")
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
   compile ':test:0.1.0' // this is the jar I need to exclude some things from

   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:1.4.0.RELEASE")
}
```

It seems like using a regular exclude clause does not work

```
compile (':test:0.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot' // doesn't work
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: That syntax should work - what does dependencyInsight say?

Comment: Running `dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency test'`
yields `:dependencyInsight :test:0.1.0 \--- compile`

Comment: Oh, I meant running it on e.g. `sprint-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. the result is: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web1.4.0 \--- compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cannot-exclude-a-depedency-inside-a-jar/19027). Apparently, it's not possible to read properties like `group` and such from a file repository. I eventually published my dependencies to a private repository ([tutorial)](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/07/maven-repository-amazon-s3.html#extend-settings-xml) and imported from there.

Comment: Ya that will also work. Create one private repo and upload it and add the url in repositories section in build.gradle.

Comment: Can you please tell me, why fileTree didn't work? Where it went wrong? What error you got?

Comment: There were no errors. The `exclude` clause just didn't do anything. No matter how what I tried to exclude. This was a few days ago so to be truthful I can't say if it was because I made a mistake in how I packed the jar or that you can't exclude from a `filetree`

Answer (score 0):

I got your point. An exclusion based on the group won't work with a flatDir repo, as a flat dir has no group information. 
So it is better to include the 'test:0.1.0' jar in the libs folder ProjectB instead of adding it in flatDir repo.
So by using fileTree we can get the dependency ProjectA(test:0.1.0 jar) for ProjectB.
From file tree we can exclude exclude a dependency inside the jar (A). 
Please go through the below code:

```
compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/lib', include: '*.jar')
```

Here we are including all the jars in  ../webserver/lib as the dependencies.

Simply use an exclude on fileTree. Syntax is the same as for include.

This should work.

Comment: Thanks. I started with `fileTree` and moved to `flatDir` because it didn't work but I might have just made a mistake. But I think it's good to point out that if the `jar` is a FatJar then this won't work either.